# how to get info like no of partitions, data within partition, partitions spread between nodes in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I have successfully started nodes, was able to do all basic things but was not able to find out how to get information about partitions, backups. could someone help me to know how to get information like no of partitions, data within partition, partitions spread between nodes, backup content information per node in Hazelcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this information can be retrieved from the PartitionService:

```
 PartitionService partitionService = hazelcastInstance.getPartitionService();
```

You can find: 
   - no of partitions
   - partitions spread between nodes

The partition content and backup content is more difficult. Normally a remote node will not ask about another partition its content. What do you want to achieve?

We provide more information through the InternalPartitionService (also which machines contains the backups), but this instance is not directly exposed to the end user and can only be accessed through reflection.

Comment: Thanks alot for reply, currently checking partitionservice and i guess  this is the class i'm for and have to find out. so what i'm trying to achieve is that i'm bit curious to find out that when i start a new node, data is spread between nodes and want to print data, backup belongs to that node in logs

Comment: Basically i assumed incorrectly that whenever i start a new node partitions are created and data is spread btw them in background, but with the help of partitionservice i was clear. so when i start the first node and added new data i could see 271 partitions are created and data,backup is spread between partitions and when i start a new node the ownership of the some existing partition was reassigned to new node, basically i checked by using key of data to find which partition it belongs to and its owner